# How to fix this error and what does this error mean in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

Now I would like to use "Speech to Text" on IBM Cloud to get Japanese text from Speech data, mp3.

However, I have gotten the same error as below after I tried it many times.

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Internal Server Error - Write</H1>
The server encountered an internal error or 
misconfiguration and was unable to
complete your request.
```

And this is my code with curl.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}"  \
--header "Content-Type: audio/mp3" \
--data-binary @{path_to_file} \
"https://gateway-tok.watsonplatform.net/speech-t 
 o-text/api/v1/recognize?model=jaJP_BroadbandModel"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the model, it should be `ja-JP_BroadbandModel`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Note that: After the **{url}** , you must type  **/v1/recognize** 

 ***audio-file.flac** is the name of the audio file

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" ^
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" ^
--data-binary @{audio file path}audio-file.flac ^
"{url}/v1/recognize"
```

Happy coding :)